# Why I can not see output in cycle (C++ simple code)?

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, cout

I would like to edit  numbers in p2 according to the code in for cycle.
But If I try to write out actual number in p2, I don´t see anything in output.
What could I change to see it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        
    int p1[10]={-5,-8,0,5,0,-8,-11,-2,1,-7};
    int p2[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    
    for(int i; i >0; i++){
        p2[i] = p2[i] - p1[i];
        cout << p2[i];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i < sizeof(p1)/sizeof(p1[0]); i++)`

Comment: Turn your compiler warnings on and then pay attention to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Ilya, you need to change the condition in the for loop. Right now, at the beginning of the for loop, `i = 0`, so the for loop never starts. Change it to the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        
    int p1[10]={-5,-8,0,5,0,-8,-11,-2,1,-7};
    int p2[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p2[i] = p2[i] - p1[i];
        cout << p2[i];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `Right now, at the beginning of the for loop, i = 0` no, value of i is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not initialize the value of `i` it takes the random value that is stored in its location.

So just make `i` 0 and loop it through until 10.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        
    int p1[10]={-5,-8,0,5,0,-8,-11,-2,1,-7};
    int p2[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p2[i] = p2[i] - p1[i];
        cout << p2[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also don't forget to return 0 when the program ended :).

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't initialize the `i` variable, it takes a random number of type int, causing the loop to misbehave. You need to make `i=0` for it to work correctly.

```
int p1[10]={-5,-8,0,5,0,-8,-11,-2,1,-7};
int p2[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

for(int i=0; i < sizeof(p1)/sizeof(p1[0]); i++){
    p2[i] = p2[i] - p1[i];
    cout << p2[i];
}
```

`sizeof(p1)/sizeof(p1[0])` is count of array elements.